# I want to create a log file where I can get INFO, DEBUG, ERROR, CRITICAL, WARNING details int that file. But My code is not giving me the exact output

Tags: python-2.7

```
import logging.handlers

LOG_FILENAME = 'logger.log'

logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    )

logging.info('In Log File...')
f = open(LOG_FILENAME, 'rt')

try:
    body = f.read()
finally:
    f.close()
print 'FILE:'
print body
def syslog (debug,info,warning,error,critical = "LEVELS"):
    str = "Debug: "+ debug+" Info: "+ info+" Waring: "+ warning+" Error: "+ error+" Critical: " +critical
    return str
my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address = ('localhost',514), facility=19)
my_logger.addHandler(handler)

my_logger.debug('this is debug')
my_logger.critical('this is critical')
my_logger.info('this is info')
my_logger.warn('this is critical')
```

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python

from flask import Flask


from src.SysMain import syslog

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    str = syslog('','','','')
    return str
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0',port=5000)

Comment: I treied with above codes but not working. Pls help me out

Comment: What output do you have and what output do you want then? Edit your question please.

Comment: @АндрейЧереваткин That code is generating file for Logs but I need that file in another machine/VM. And I want to just call the function for my logger so I can get the logs of my project into my file. All other functions are on different machines. I need to coordinate with those codes and generate file in my machine

Comment: You want the machine to write logs to some other machine? Well, it is possible, but I want to confirm it before I start writing a long answer) @swathi

Comment: @АндрейЧереваткин, Ha yes,   write logs from one machine(vm)  to some other machine (vm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could establish a central log server and send all log messages from all machines to it via HTTP (or sockets).

`logging` module has many features, including so-called handlers. Simply put, a logging handler is a class whose `emit` method takes the log record to input and does something with it, for example, writing the record to a given file is default behavior (`FileHandler`). There is a lot of handlers already included in `logging` module which could be useful. In your case, you could use [`HTTPHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#httphandler). `SocketHandler` is described on the same page, you can use it if you prefer sockets.

Or you could write your own custom handler

```
class CustomHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        # msg is the record string to, em, record (sorry for much of a muchness)
        # Do whatever you want with it
```

`HTTPHandler` and your custom handler are added to a logger just as in your code

```
handler = logging.handlers.HTTPHandler(...)
```

or

```
handler = CustomHandler(...)
```

```
my_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply

Comment: @ Андрей Череваткин ,No problem yar ,thanks for Reply. I found the solution  that code but  i added few things to that code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging
import socket
import sys
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler

#class ContextFilter(object):
    #pass
class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    hostname = socket.gethostname()

    def filter(self, record):
        record.hostname = ContextFilter.hostname
        return True

    try:
        syslog = SysLogHandler(address=('110.110.112.143', 514))
    # except (IOError,NameError) as e:
    #     print str(e)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception("message contextfilter")
    finally:
        pass

        #try:
            #handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=('localhost', 514), facility=19)
            # except (IOError,NameError) as e:
            #     print str(e)
        #except Exception as e:
            #logging.exception("message contextfilter")
        #finally:
        #pass


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

f = ContextFilter()
logger.addFilter(f)

# syslog = SysLogHandler(address=('110.110.112.202', 514))
# handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address = '/dev/log')
# handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=('localhost', 514), facility=19)
# logger.addHandler(handler)
# syslog = SysLogHandler(address=('192.168.56.102', 514))
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(hostname)s syslogs: [%(levelname)s] %(message)s', datefmt='%b %d %H:%M:%S')
# syslog.setFormatter(formatter)
# logger.addHandler(syslog)

#  NullHandler handler excepation
logging.getLogger('ContextFilter').addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
logging.debug("In Information's Log File... ")
logging.info("In Debug's Log File... ")
logging.warning("In Warning's Log File... ")
logging.error("In Critical's Log File... ")
logging.critical("In Error's Log File...")
print "These is loging INFO .... "
```